# Applying ThemeOverlay for custom theming a MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialog

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, material-components-android

My app theme is set up like this:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/appColorOnSurface</item>
...
</style>
```

But when I use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` the text contrast is very poor (because material dialog uses [colorOnSurface with 60% alpha](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/color/material_on_surface_emphasis_medium.xml), instead of `textColorPrimary`). So I tried to use this ThemeOverlay:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Dialog.HighContrast" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/appColorOnSurfaceHighContrast</item>
</style>
```

and applying it like this:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Dialog.HighContrast</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/appColorOnSurface</item>
    ...
</style>
```

However, this causes problems when displaying a list of items in the dialog. Each item touch area is limited to the area of text being displayed instead of stretching the width of the dialog like normal.

Furthermore, the theme does not appear to be Material, but rather AppCompat style.

Why does the ThemeOverlay approach cause the unexpected touch area (as if `WRAP_CONTENT`) issue? Is that not the correct way to apply a ThemeOverlay? Or is there another way to get the alert dialog to use `@color/appColorOnSurfaceHighContrast`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog` instead of `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert`, and also using `materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle` to make sure only the dialog text body was being styled:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Dialog.HighContrast" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App.Body.Text.HighContrast</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App.Body.Text.HighContrast" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/appColorOnSurfaceHighContrast</item>
</style>
```

But why does AndroidStudio auto-complete only show `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` and not `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`?

Note: there were actually two issues going on here:

1. Changing the parent ThemeOverlay from `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog` to `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` fixed the touch area issue, but I was still getting an AppCompat (non-Material) theme.
2. Changing the parent ThemeOverlay from `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` to `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog` fixed the theme to make it appear Material.

UPDATE: It looks like `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` is for use with `alertDialogTheme` and `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog` is for use with `materialAlertDialogTheme`. See: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/values/themes.xml#L60

However, that still doesn't explain why the latter doesn't auto-complete.